# wp.customize, get value from a setting and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am currently working on the theme options for a custom theme for a client. For further use i want to store a few settings inside variables during the page load of the customizer screen.

After a bit of a struggle i used wp.customize object to get the value of the setting i required and store it inside the variable. However the information of the variable can not be accessed outside of the function, even tho i declared the variable outside of the function. I have posted the function below.

The console log inside the function posts the value that i need. The console log outside of the function returns undefined. I would like some help on getting this to work.

Thank you in advance, Nick

```
var e_linkedin;
var e_facebook;
var e_twitter;
var e_google;

wp.customize( 'theme_social[enable_facebook]', function( value ) {
    e_facebook = value['_value'];
    console.log(e_facebook);

});
console.log(e_facebook);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the variables from the customizer like this:

`var yourval = wp.customize.value( 'theme_social[enable_facebook]' )();`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its been a long while since i asked this question and the problem has since then been resolved. Guess i should close this question down now :-).

Comment: What is the solution? I am looking to solve something similar

Answer (score 1):

Access the value parameter with `value._value`.

Comment: There has to be another way.  Values with an underscore shouldn't be accessed directly.